# I'm trying to make a chart from a query and I keep getting an "Invalid chart query" error

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-apex

The query I am using is displayed below

```
select 
    Offence_Name, sum(No_Of_Offences)  
from 
    Area_Offence  
group by 
    Offence_Name;
```

Comment: Can you please share the `Area_Offence` table's structure and the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Invalid chart query: Select Offence_Name , sum(No_Of_Offences) from Area_Offence group by Offence_Name 

Use the following syntax:
SELECT LINK, LABEL, VALUE
FROM   ...
Or use the following syntax for a query returning multiple series:
SELECT LINK, LABEL, VALUE1 [, VALUE2 [, VALUE3...]]
FROM   ...
LINK URL
LABEL Text that displays along a chart axis.
VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3... Numeric columns that define the data values.
Note: The series names for Column and Line charts are derived from the column aliases used in the query.

Comment: it works when i run the query in SQL but i get this error when i try to use the query to create a report

Comment: Are you using Oracle Application Express?

Comment: yh im using Oracle Application Express

Comment: Ah huh! Now it makes more sense. I've edited the question's tags to highlight that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle APEX, your query must have three columns - `link` (to drilldown data, usually), `value` and `label`.  So, in your case:

```
SELECT
    NULL AS link, Offence_Name AS label, SUM(No_Of_Offences) AS value
FROM
    Area_Offence  
GROUP BY
    Offence_Name;
```

Comment: i have tried this query and it still gives me the same error

Comment: @bev got my column order mixed up - please retry with my edited query.